# How can RenderPartialToString in asp.net Core 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, partial-views

I need to render a certain partialView as string,  in core 2 ?

Anyone can help me to creat this ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you show any sample code?  What problems have you encountered?  This is not an uncommon function to have in an ASP.NET Core project...there are numerous blog posts and samples on Github you could find from a simple web search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

#### Interface

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DL.SO.Framework.Mvc.ViewEngine
{
    public interface IRazorViewRenderer
    {
        Task<string> RenderToStringAsync<T>(T model, string viewPath);
    }
}
```

#### Implementation

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DL.SO.Framework.Mvc.ViewEngine
{
    public class SimpleRazorViewRenderer : IRazorViewRenderer
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private readonly IRazorViewEngine _razorViewEngine;
        private readonly ITempDataProvider _tempDataProvider;
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
        private readonly IOptions<MvcViewOptions> _viewOptions;

        public SimpleRazorViewRenderer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
            IRazorViewEngine razorViewEngine,
            ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider,
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
            IOptions<MvcViewOptions> viewOptions)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            _razorViewEngine = razorViewEngine;
            _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
            _viewOptions = viewOptions;
        }

        public async Task<string> RenderToStringAsync<T>(T model, string viewPath)
        {
            var actionContext = GetActionContext();
            var view = FindView(actionContext, viewPath);

            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                    actionContext,
                    view,
                    new ViewDataDictionary<T>(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary())
                    {
                        Model = model
                    },
                    new TempDataDictionary(actionContext.HttpContext, _tempDataProvider),
                    sw,
                    _viewOptions.Value.HtmlHelperOptions
                );

                await view.RenderAsync(viewContext);

                return sw.ToString();
            }
        }

        private IView FindView(ActionContext actionContext, string viewPath)
        {
            var getViewResult = _razorViewEngine.GetView(null, viewPath, true);
            if (getViewResult.Success)
            {
                return getViewResult.View;
            }

            var findViewResult = _razorViewEngine.FindView(actionContext, viewPath, true);
            if (findViewResult.Success)
            {
                return findViewResult.View;
            }

            var searchedLocations = getViewResult.SearchedLocations.Concat(findViewResult.SearchedLocations);
            var errorMessage = String.Join(
                Environment.NewLine,
                new[] { $"Unable to find view '{ viewPath }'. The following locations were searched:" }.Concat(searchedLocations)); ;

            throw new InvalidOperationException(errorMessage);
        }

        private ActionContext GetActionContext()
        {
            var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
            var routingFeature = httpContext.Features.Get<IRoutingFeature>();

            return new ActionContext(
                httpContext,
                routingFeature.RouteData,
                new ActionDescriptor());
        }
    }
}
```

#### Register on Startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddScoped<IRazorViewRenderer, SimpleRazorViewRenderer>();

    ...
}
```

#### How to use it

```
namespace DL.SO.Web.UI.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IEmailService _emailService;
        private readonly IRazorViewRenderer _viewRenderer;

        public HomeController(IEmailService emailService,
            IRazorViewRenderer viewRenderer)
        {
            _emailService = emailService;
            _viewRenderer = viewRenderer;
        }

        public IActionResult Contact()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Contact(ContactViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Json(new {
                    Status = false,
                    Message = "Something wrong"
                });
            }

            // I have the template/partial view under Shared/EmailTemplates folder
            // but you can put it right in the Shared folder too
            const string emailTemplatePath = "EmailTemplates/_ContactEmail";

            var emailModel = new ContactEmailModel
            {
                VisitorFullName = model.FullName,
                VisitorEmail = model.Email,
                Company = model.Company,
                Message = model.Message
            };

            // Calling the view renderer to parse the partial view into
            // string
            var emailContent = await _viewRenderer.RenderToStringAsync(
                emailModel, emailTemplatePath);

            // Send out email with my custom email service
            _emailService.SendAsync("Customer Message", emailContent, 
                model.Email, "to@sample.com");

            return Json(new {
                Status = true,
                Message = @"Your message is sent and you should receive
                    a confirmation email."
            });
        }
    }
}
```

#### The partial view / Template _ContactEmail.cshtml

```
@model DL.SO.Web.UI.EmailModels.Contact.ContactEmailModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<p>Hello @Model.VisitorFullName,</p>
<p>
    Thanks for contacting us. We have received your message and will 
    try to response to you as soon as possible.
</p>
<p>
    Below is your message summary:
</p>
<ul>
    <li><small>Your name: </small> @Model.VisitorFullName</li>
    <li><small>Email: </small> @Model.VisitorEmail</li>
    @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Company))
    {
        <li><small>Company: </small> @Model.Company</li>
    }
    <li><small>Message: </small> @Model.Message</li>
</ul>
<p>
    Thank you,<br />
    David Liang
</p>
```

Comment: You need to explain what was not working, what exceptions/errors you saw and give out more details/feedbacks after you try instead of "not working. You fix it for me."

Comment: Ajax:
  success: function (e) {
if (e.Status) {
$("#ic").text("");
$("#ic").append(e.Message);
 }
else {
alert("NOTOKAY");
}

When i send parameter with Ajax to Action , Every Thing is okay , this is my action Code :

return Json(new JsonData()
{  Status = true,
Message = await _viewRenderService.RenderToStringAsync( model,"_GetCatByTopicId")
});

the "NOTOKAY" alert is displayed .

Comment: Where did you put the view `_GetCatByTopicId`? And you can always run the application in Debug mode and put a breakpoint inside `.RenderToStringAsync()` to see if that's getting called.

Comment: Sure , but can u guide me , how to use (call) that in controller (homecontroller)?

Comment: Very helpful , Thank you David.

Comment: Good post! However, IServiceProvider serviceProvider is not used.

Comment: Don't forget add `builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` in `Program.cs`.